# how to pass same parameter and method name in get and delete methods in web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Employee(int id)
    {
        Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(employee);
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public IHttpActionResult Employee( int id)
    {
        Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Employees.Remove(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(employee);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right: just rename the methods to `GetEmployee` and `DeleteEmployee`.

C# doesn't allow methods with the same name that have an identical number of arguments of the same type.

Renaming the methods takes care of that and the ASP.NET routing will still be able to match the correct methods to your routes because of the attributes that the methods are decorated with.

Comment: can you tell me "how to retrieve specific field from mode without showing rest of the field" my fields that i wanted to retrieve is Name,Department,Manager by using "LINQ"